# ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server

Tags: node.js, ejs

This is shown in the lab environment:

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0, intensity = 0 WHERE id = 1' at line 1.

I don't know why it keeps showing me this error, no matter what I do to try to "update my device"
below is the table:
[image: myDevices table]
below is the devices that can't be updated, other devices that I have can be updated, for these that can't it keep showing the same error, whether or not it has anything to do with intensity,
[image: show devices-update the devices]
when edit device is click, will be redirected to the update page
[image]
but, when i click edit this device on this page, the error will show.

```
app.post("/backend-update", function (req, res) {
        let sqlquery = "UPDATE myDevices SET status = '" + req.body.status + "', state = '" + req.body.state + "', temperature = " + req.body.temperature + ", volume = " + req.body.volume + ", speed = " + req.body.speed + ", intensity = " + req.body.intensity + " WHERE id = " + req.body.id;
        
        const html = "<html><body><br><form action='/showDeviceStatus'><input type='submit' value='Back'></form></body></html>"
        db.query(sqlquery, (err, update) => {
            if (err) {
                // return res.send("<html><p><b>ERROR!!!</b> Click Back to try again.</p></html>" + html);
                return console.error(err.message)
            }
            else {
                return res.send("<html><p>Your device have been successfully <b>updated</b>! Click Back to continue.</p></html>" + html);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you print out the SQL statement you're trying to execute and share it?

Comment: let sqlquery = "UPDATE myDevices SET status = '" + req.body.status + "', state = '" + req.body.state + "', temperature = " + req.body.temperature + ", volume = " + req.body.volume + ", speed = " + req.body.speed + ", intensity = " + req.body.intensity + " WHERE id = " + req.body.id;

Comment: is it this you are refering

Comment: No, the result of that.

Comment: Add something like `console.log(sqlquery)` after that line and share the output

Comment: UPDATE myDevices SETstatus =On,state =,temperature =On,volume =0,speed =0,0,intensity =0 WHERE id = 1

Comment: i am not sure why it turns out like that, state should be NA, temperature should be 45 not On, there is an extra 0 behind speed